# What does "$\mathbb{F^n}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self learning **Linear Algebra** using "Linear Algebra Done Right" a book by Sheldon Axler. And for me its important to understand the smallest thing mentioned in  the book. Can someone explain to me what the author means by **OVER** R/C? 
And there should be a reason he mentioned this (an importance), can someone explain me that? This is what the  book says :

$\mathbb{R^n}$ is a vector space **over** $\mathbb{R}$,

and $\mathbb{C^n}$ is a vector space **over** $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Have you seen the definition of a vector space yet?

Comment: @Seth Im at the part of defining a vector space in the book.

Comment: The following was copied from the book.

Comment: @GitGud , Yes I quoted the exact words from the book because I don't understand what those statements mean :)

Comment: The scalar multiplication in a vector space depends upon $\mathbb F$. Thus
when we need to be precise, we will say that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb F$
instead of saying simply that $V$ is a vector space. For example, $\mathbb R^n$ is
a vector space over $\mathbb R$, and $\mathbb C^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb C$. Frequently, a
vector space over $\mathbb R$ is called a real vector space and a vector space over $\mathbb C$ is called a complex vector space.

Comment: Usually the choice of $\mathbb F$ is either
obvious from the context or irrelevant, and thus we often assume that
$\mathbb F$ is lurking in the background without specifically mentioning it.
Elements of a vector space are called vectors or points. This geometric
language sometimes aids our intuition.
Not surprisingly, $\mathbb F^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb F$, as you should verify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the ingredients of a vector space is a definition of scalar multiplication; but you need to know what field the scalars are in! A vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$ has as part of its data a map (scalar multiplication) $\mathbb{F}\times V\to V$. The same set $V$ could be given a different vector space structure with a multiplication map $\mathbb{K}\times V$; this is most common when $\mathbb{K}\subset\mathbb{F}$, and the second map is simply a restriction of the first one.

For example, $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ as you mention in the question, but it is also a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, since you can simply restrict scalar multiplication to real scalars. These two structures are quite different; for example, the single element $1$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{C}$, since every complex number is of the form $z\cdot 1$ for some unique $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Over $\mathbb{R}$, one possible basis is $1,i$, since every complex number is of the form $a+bi$ for a unique pair $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Notice that the dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ changed depending on whether we gave it the structure of a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ or over $\mathbb{R}$.